# Symfony2 add attr to field and not label using FormBuilder

Tags: forms, symfony, formbuilder

How can I add a attribute to field only using FormBuilder (not twig form theming).
When I use

```
$builder->add('body',null,array('attr' => array('class' => 'tinymce')));
```

It's add a `tinymce` class to label too. Please help.

Comment: It's not possible to do this without any changes to the form theme. I asked something very similar before. Take a look at the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11034736/1456376

Comment: ok, thanks. I think I will use a JS for that: `$('label.tinymce').removeClass('tinymce');` because it is shortest

Comment: I just retested with my installation of Symfony2 - and this code applies `class` only to `input`, label is not changed. Which version of Symfony2 do you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
$builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class ) //will display default label
            ->add('username', TextType::class,
                array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
//                      'class' => 'myclassfrom.css', //<- this one is realy avesome
                        'placeholder' => 'UsernameExample',
                        'autofocus' => '',

                    ),
            ))
```